# Why QGrapchicsScene invalidate for foreground seems to throws updating on itemlayer?

Tags: qt, qgraphicsview

I have a 'map' with 100.000 rectangles at the 'itemslayer',
I want to have a dynamic line creation and I draw it at Foreground layer. (That is, I dont want to have a lot of updates... )
The performance is poor, you note the mouse heavy to move, An I think that is an update for every rectangle that this line 'touchs' .
What is for the foregroundlayer then? I thought that It'd let me to draw over a grapchisview without updating the itemlayer...
Maybe it is related with there is not cache for foreground ?
Any idea ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When I was reading the documentation on 4.8.0 and it states this:

*Note that QGraphicsView currently supports background caching only (see QGraphicsView::CacheBackground). This function is equivalent to calling update() if any layer but QGraphicsScene::BackgroundLayer is passed.*

So, if you just want to update the foreground layer, then it will draw everything anyways, bummer...

I know it's not a answer, but it does confirm what you are seeing.